# Use gzip to compress the files in a directory except for already existing .gz files

Tags: gzip

I have a directory of logs that I would like to set up a job to compress using [gzip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip). The issue is I don't want to recompress the logs I've already compressed.

I tried using `ls | grep -v gz | gzip`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to do this? Basically I want to gzip every file in the directory that does not end in .gz.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can just do:

```
gzip *
```

gzip will tell you it skips the files that already have a `.gz`  ending.
If that message gets in the way you can use:

```
gzip -q *
```

---

What you tried did not work, because `gzip` doesn't read the filenames of the files to compress from stdin, for that to work you would have to use:

```
ls | grep -v gz | xargs gzip
```

You will exclude files with the pattern `gz` anywhere in the file name, not just at the end.¹ You also have to take note that parsing the output of `ls` is dangerous when you have file names with spaces, newlines, etc., are involved.

A more clean solution, not relying on `gzip` to skip files with a `.gz` ending is, that also handles non-compressed files in subdirectories:

```
find .  -type f ! -name "*.gz" -exec gzip {} \;
```

---

¹ <sub>As `izkata` commented: using `.gz` alone to improve this, would not work. You would need to use `grep -vF .gz` or `grep -v '\.gz$'`. That still leaves the danger of processing `ls`' output</sub>

Comment: "...that makes it less likely to match some internal part of a filename" - it's grep, just use `$` so it's clearer.  And you didn't escape the `.` anyway, so it's only going to exclude files that _start_ with `gz` (since they don't have "any character before `gz`")

Comment: @Izkata: No, including the unescaped dot and not anchoring the regex with `$` going to exclude (`-v`) all files that have names consisting of three or more characters including any character followed by "gz" anywhere in the filename. So it will *include* files with names that start with "gz".

Comment: @DennisWilliamson My last comment wasn't clear, it's also going to exclude files with `gz` anywhere in the name (except the start).  So it's better to anchor it anyway.  Having not used `$`, it read as though you didn't realize what `.` means in a regex, hence the rest of the confusing comment.